# Dynamically render choropleth map with sliderInput in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have shapefile which I am reading into R using readOGR to convert it to SpatialPolygonDataframe. The attribute table looks as shown in the figure below.

[image]

Each row is a zone (postal code area) and there are values for each hour of the day eg: h_0, h_1, ...h_23 measured for each zone. In my shiny app I want to show a map which changes as the user select a particular hour using sliderInput widget. The shiny app looks like below:

[image]

The code that produces the above result is here:

```
 library(shiny)
 library(leaflet)
 library(reshape2)
 library(maps)
 library(mapproj)
 library(rgdal)
 library(RColorBrewer)
 library(sp)
 library(rgeos)



ui <- fluidPage(

 titlePanel("Title"),

 sidebarLayout(

 sidebarPanel(
   tabsetPanel(id= "tabs",

              tabPanel("Map", id = "Map", 
                       br(), 

                       p("Choose options below to interact with the Map"), 

                       sliderInput("hour", "Select the hours", min = 0 , max = 23, 
                                   value = 7, step = 1, dragRange= TRUE)
                       )
  )
),

mainPanel(

  tabsetPanel(type= "tabs",


              tabPanel("Map", leafletOutput(outputId = "map"))
          )
  )
 )
 )



 server <- function(input, output) {


  layer <- reactive( {

      shp = readOGR("shp",layer = "attractiveness_day3")
      shp_p <- spTransform(shp, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))

  })

 output$map <- renderLeaflet({
     bins<- c(0, 2000, 4000, 8000, 16000, Inf)
    pal <- colorBin("YlOrRd", domain = layer()$h_7, bins = bins)

    leaflet(layer()) %>% 
    setView(13.4, 52.5, 9) %>% 
    addTiles()%>%
      addPolygons( 
        fillColor = ~pal(h_7),
        weight = 0.0,
        opacity = 1,
        color = "white",
        dashArray = "3",
        fillOpacity = 0.7 
      )  %>% 
      addLegend(pal = pal, values = ~h_7, opacity = 0.7, title = NULL, position = "bottomright")


  })
  #until here it works but onwards not. 
 observe(leafletProxy("map", layer())%>%
           clearShapes()%>%
           addPolygons( 
             fillColor = ~pal(h_7),  # is it possible here to pass column name dynamically
             weight = 0.0,
             opacity = 1,
             color = "white",
             dashArray = "3",
             fillOpacity = 0.7 
           )  %>% 
           addLegend(pal = pal, values = ~h_7, opacity = 0.7, title = NULL, position = "bottomright")
 )

}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So currently the choropleth map is populated  with values of column `h_7` selected statically. But I don't know how and whether I can dynamically pass the column name based on sliderInput selection ( For eg. If sliderInput value is 8 the corresponding column is h_8).  And then render the map based on the selected column passed from reactive funnction to the `observe` and `leafletProxy` functions.

sample data : [sample data](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ybziyi1pbdwjkb7/AADNUPHWljy0vS4lH4z-V_v4a?dl=0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to pass the column names as a string. In `leafletProxy` you can link to your column values with `dataset[[column_name]]`. With a single square bracket you are not only selecting the values, but also the corresponding polygons.

For your app to work you need to call `layer()` outside the `leafletProxy` function. In addition, use `clearControls()` to remove duplicate legends.

Finally, I am not sure why you put your shapefile in a `reactive` expression. It wil also work if you just add it as a variable in your `server`.

```
 observeEvent({input$hour},{
    hour_column <- paste0('h_',input$hour)
    data = layer()[hour_column]
    pal <- colorBin("YlOrRd", domain = as.numeric(data[[hour_column]]), bins = bins)
    leafletProxy("map", data=data)%>%
      clearShapes()%>%
      addPolygons( 
        fillColor = pal(as.numeric(data[[hour_column]])),  
        weight = 0.0,
        opacity = 1,
        color = "white",
        dashArray = "3",
        fillOpacity = 0.7 
      )  %>% clearControls() %>%
      addLegend(pal = pal, values =as.numeric(data[[hour_column]]), opacity = 0.7, title = NULL, position = "bottomright")
  })
```