# R Shiny/R Leaflet/ R : Dynamically render choropleth map with sliderInput in R shiny 2

Tags: r, shiny, qgis, shinyapps, r-leaflet

I am trying to use the slider function to select and only display selected polygons using Shiny on a Leaflet map.

The code below gets the slider to react, but I want the colour scale to represent the depth, and the slider to select and display the energy polygons (removing non-relevant polygons) but with the depth colour scale. The polygon files contain both the depth and energy data.

The following question points me in the right direction. But I cannot get this to work with my data.

[Dynamically render choropleth map with sliderInput in R shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53480924/dynamically-render-choropleth-map-with-sliderinput-in-r-shiny/53482005#53482005)

Shapefile wave-shp (wave.shp) on the following page: https://www.renewables-atlas.info/downloads/.

Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(RColorBrewer)

wave_data <- read_sf("~/path/Wave.shp")

wave_data <- st_transform(wave_data, crs = '+proj=longlat 
+datum=WGS84')

wave_data2 <- wave_data %>% 
mutate_at(vars(An_mn_P_OD), ~ as.integer(round(.x))) 

## Load map

wave_data_map <- leaflet() %>% 
   addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldTopoMap) %>% 
   setView(lng = -4.2026458, lat = 56.4906712, zoom = 5)
wave_data_map

bins <- c(0, 25, 50, 100, 150, 200, 300, 400, 500, 1000, 3100)
pal <- colorBin("RdYlBu", domain = wave_data2$Ave_Depth, bins = 
bins)

## Add polygons

wave_data_map <- leaflet() %>% 
   addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldTopoMap) %>% 
   setView(lng = -4.2026458, lat = 56.4906712, zoom = 5) %>% 
   addPolygons(data = wave_data2, 
           weight = 1,
           smoothFactor = 0.5,
           color = "white", 
           fillOpacity = 0.5, 
           fillColor = pal(wave_data2$Ave_Depth), 
           
)
wave_data_map

## Add legend

wave_data_map <- leaflet() %>% 
   addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldTopoMap) %>% 
   setView(lng = -4.2026458, lat = 56.4906712, zoom = 5) %>% 
   addPolygons(data = wave_data2, 
           weight = 1,
           smoothFactor = 0.5,
           color = "white", 
           fillOpacity = 0.3, 
           fillColor = pal(wave_data2$Ave_Depth)) %>% 
   addLegend(pal = pal, 
         values = wave_data2$Ave_Depth, 
         title = "Average depth",
         labFormat = labelFormat (suffix = "m"),
         opacity = 0.7, 
         position = "bottomright")
wave_data_map


# Define UI for application

ui <- bootstrapPage(
   tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body 
                {width:100%;height:100%}"),
   leafletOutput("wave_data_map", width = "100%", height = 
                  "100%"),
   sliderInput("wave_data_slider", "Wave energy", 
                         min = 0, max = 75, 
                         value = c(min(wave_data2$An_mn_P_OD), 
                         max(wave_data2$An_mn_P_OD)), 
                         step = 5, 
                         round = 0.5,
                         dragRange = TRUE)
))


# Define server logic

server <- function(input, output, session) {
 wave_energy_output <- reactive ({
    wave_data2 %>% 
    filter(An_mn_P_OD >= input$wave_data_range[1]) %>% 
    filter(An_mn_P_OD <= input$wave_data_range[2]) %>% 
     group_by(Lat)
 })
output$wave_data_map <- renderLeaflet(
  leaflet() %>% 
     addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldTopoMap) %>% 
     setView(lng = -4.2026458, lat = 56.4906712, zoom = 5) %>% 
     addPolygons(data = wave_data2, 
                 weight = 1,
                 smoothFactor = 0.5,
                 color = "white", 
                 fillOpacity = 0.3, 
                 fillColor = pal(wave_data2$Ave_Depth)) %>% 
     addLegend(pal = pal, 
               values = wave_data2$Ave_Depth, 
               title = "Average depth",
               labFormat = labelFormat (suffix = "m"),
               opacity = 0.7, 
               position = "bottomright")
)

observeEvent({input$wave_data_slider}, {
    data = wave_energy_output()[wave_data2$An_mn_P_OD]
  leafletProxy("wave_data_map", data = wave_data2) %>% 
     clearShapes() %>% 
     addPolygons(data = wave_energy_output,
        fillColor = pal, 
        weight = 0.0, 
        opacity = 1, 
        color = "white", 
        dashArray = 3, 
        fillOpacity = 0.7, 
     ) %>% clearControls() %>% 
     addLegend(pal = pal, 
               values = wave_data2$Ave_Depth, 
               title = "Average depth",
               labFormat = labelFormat (suffix = "m"),
               opacity = 0.7, 
               position = "bottomright")
  
}
)}

# Run the application 

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

NEW ERROR:

Warning: Error in [: Can't subset columns past the end.
ℹ Locations 43, 57, 57, …, 48, and 46 don't exist.
ℹ There are only 42 columns.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(RColorBrewer)

wave_data <- read_sf("~/path/Wave.shp")

wave_data <- st_transform(wave_data, crs = '+proj=longlat 
+datum=WGS84')

wave_data2 <- wave_data %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(An_mn_P_OD), ~ as.integer(round(.x))) 

## Load map

wave_data_map <- leaflet() %>% 
   addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldTopoMap) %>% 
   setView(lng = -4.2026458, lat = 56.4906712, zoom = 5)
wave_data_map

bins <- c(0, 25, 50, 100, 150, 200, 300, 400, 500, 1000, 3100)
pal <- colorBin("RdYlBu", domain = wave_data2$Ave_Depth, bins = bins)

# Define UI for application

ui <- bootstrapPage(
   tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body 
             {width:100%;height:100%}"),
   leafletOutput("wave_data_map", width = "100%", height = 
                "100%"),
   absolutePanel(top = 10, right = 10, 
   sliderInput("wave_data_range", "Wave energy", 
           min = 0, max = 75, 
           value = c(min(wave_data2$An_mn_P_OD), 
                     max(wave_data2$An_mn_P_OD)), 
           step = 5, 
           round = 0.5,
           dragRange = TRUE)
))

# Define server logic

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   wave_energy_output <- reactive({
      data <- wave_data2 %>% 
         filter(An_mn_P_OD >= input$wave_data_range[1],
            An_mn_P_OD <= input$wave_data_range[2])
      data %>% group_by(Lat)
   })

  output$wave_data_map <- renderLeaflet({
   leaflet() %>% 
     addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldTopoMap) %>% 
     setView(lng = -4.2026458, lat = 56.4906712, zoom = 5) %>% 
     addPolygons(data = wave_data2, 
                 weight = 1,
                 smoothFactor = 0.5,
                 color = "white", 
                 fillOpacity = 0.3, 
                 fillColor = pal(wave_data2$Ave_Depth)) %>% 
     addLegend(pal = pal, 
               values = wave_data2$Ave_Depth, 
               title = "Average depth",
               labFormat = labelFormat (suffix = "m"),
               opacity = 0.7, 
               position = "bottomright")
 })

 observeEvent(input$wave_data_range, {
    data <- wave_energy_output()
    leafletProxy("wave_data_map", data = data) %>% 
     clearShapes() %>% 
     addPolygons(data = data,
                 fillColor = pal(wave_energy_output()$Ave_Depth), 
                 weight = 1,
                 smoothFactor = 0.5,
                 color = "white", 
                 fillOpacity = 0.3)
   })

}

# Run the application 

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```