# R markdown not knitting to HTML?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, r-leaflet

I cannot get both the markdown document to knit to html and the shiny code to function simulaneously. Here is my code:

````
---
title: "Report"
author: "Name"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
    runtime: shiny
editor_options: 
  markdown: 
    wrap: 72
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(htmlwidgets)
```

## Summary

Text

## Section

Text

```{r, echo = FALSE}

wave_data <- read_sf("~/path/Wave_data_32631.geojson")

wave_data <- st_transform(wave_data, crs = '+proj=longlat 
+datum=WGS84')

wave_data2 <- wave_data %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(An_mn_P_OD), ~ as.integer(round(.x))) 

bins <- c(0, 25, 50, 100, 150, 200, 300, 400, 500, 1000, 3100)
pal <- colorBin("RdYlBu", domain = wave_data2$Ave_Depth, bins = bins)

# Define UI for application

ui <- bootstrapPage(
   tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body 
             {width:100%;height:100%}"),
   leafletOutput("wave_data_map", width = "100%", height = 
                    "100%"),
   absolutePanel(top = 10, right = 10, 
                 sliderInput("wave_data_range", "Wave energy", 
                         min = 0, max = 75, 
                         value = c(min(wave_data2$An_mn_P_OD), 
                                   max(wave_data2$An_mn_P_OD)), 
                         step = 5, 
                         round = 0.5,
                         dragRange = TRUE)
 )
 )

 # Define server logic

 server <- function(input, output, session) {
 wave_energy_output <- reactive({
    data <- wave_data2 %>% 
       filter(An_mn_P_OD >= input$wave_data_range[1],
            An_mn_P_OD <= input$wave_data_range[2])
   data %>% group_by(Lat)
 })

output$wave_data_map <- renderLeaflet({
   leaflet() %>% 
     addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldTopoMap) %>% 
     setView(lng = -4.2026458, lat = 56.4906712, zoom = 5) %>% 
     addPolygons(data = wave_data2, 
                 weight = 1,
                 smoothFactor = 0.5,
                 color = "white", 
                 fillOpacity = 0.3, 
                 fillColor = pal(wave_data2$Ave_Depth)) %>% 
     addLegend(pal = pal, 
               values = wave_data2$Ave_Depth, 
               title = "Average depth",
               labFormat = labelFormat (suffix = "m"),
               opacity = 0.7, 
               position = "bottomright")
 })

 observeEvent(input$wave_data_range, {
  data <- wave_energy_output()
  leafletProxy("wave_data_map", data = data) %>% 
     clearShapes() %>% 
     addPolygons(data = data,
                 fillColor = pal(wave_energy_output()$Ave_Depth), 
                 weight = 1,
                 smoothFactor = 0.5,
                 color = "white", 
                 fillOpacity = 0.5)
 })

 }

 # Run the application 

 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

 ```

 ## Section

 ## Section
````

I have tried several iterations, it seems if I can get the shiny app to work the document will not knit to html, if I can knit to html, the shiny app doesn't work.

Please see earlier question if full capabiities necessary: [R Shiny/R Leaflet/ R : Dynamically render choropleth map with sliderInput in R shiny 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75501282/r-shiny-r-leaflet-r-dynamically-render-choropleth-map-with-sliderinput-in-r-s)

Any help always very much appreciated.

Comment: Not reproducible since we don't have your wave data file.

Comment: As stated above, see earlier question for full capabities.